# Macbook as gateway for fedora?

Tags: gateway

I have an EVDO usb modem that works on my macbook. I am looking to use internet on my fedora notebook. I am thinking of connecting the two via an ethernet hub and then making the macbook as the gateway for the fedora notebook. Do i have to do anything more than enable ip forwarding on the macbook from /etc/hostconfig and set the gateway address on my fedora notebook as the macbook's ip?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the macbook is running OS X, just turn on internet sharing in the control panel, and run DHCP on the other machine.

You probably don't even need the hub, the Mac's ethernet is auto-MDI/MDX so it'll configure itself as a crossover.